# Implementing 'if' statements into for loops

Tags: python, optimization, keras

I am attempting to optimize a Convolutional Neural Network using a grid search but am encountering an issue when I try to determine how many Dense and Convolutional layers should be used when doing a grid search.

Ideally it would add the Convolutional Layers first (depending on the trial) and then add the Dense layers afterwards.

```
###     ~~~CREATING MODEL~~~

dense_layers = [0, 1, 2]
conv_layers = [1, 2, 3]
layer_sizes = [16, 32, 64, 128]
layer_sizec1 = [16, 32, 64, 128]
layer_sizec2 = [16, 32, 64, 128]
layer_sizec3 = [16, 32, 64, 128]
layer_size1d = [16, 32, 64, 128]
layer_size2d = [16, 32, 64, 128]


for dense_layer in dense_layers:
    for layer_sizec1 in layer_sizec1:
        for layer_sizec2 in layer_sizec2:
            for layer_sizec3 in layer_sizec3:
                for layer_size1d in layer_size1d:
                    for layer_size2d in layer_size2d:
                        for conv_layer in conv_layers:
                            NAME = "{}-conv-{}-nodes-{}-dense-{}".format(conv_layer, layer_size, dense_layer, int(time.time()))
                            print(NAME)

                            model = Sequential()

                            model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3), input_shape = input_shape))
                            model.add(Activation('relu'))
                            model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

                            if conv_layer == '1':
                                model.add(Conv2D(layer_sizec1, (3, 3)))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

                            if conv_layer == '2':
                                model.add(Conv2D(layer_sizec1, (3, 3)))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
                                model.add(Conv2D(layer_sizec2, (3, 3)))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

                            if conv_layer == '3':
                                model.add(Conv2D(layer_sizec1, (3, 3)))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
                                model.add(Conv2D(layer_sizec2, (3, 3)))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
                                model.add(Conv2D(layer_sizec3, (3, 3)))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

                            model.add(Flatten())

                            if dense_layer == '0':

                            if dense_layer == '1':
                                model.add(Dense(layer_size1d))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))            

                            if dense_layer == '2':
                                model.add(Dense(layer_size1d))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))
                                model.add(Dense(layer_size2d))
                                model.add(Activation('relu'))

                            model.add(Dense(10))
                            model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

                            model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

                            model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size = 128, nb_epoch = 10, validation_data=(X_val, Y_val), callbacks = [tensorboard])
```

It displays the following generic message after running.

```
Error Message: 

  File "<ipython-input-33-f7d41bf08db6>", line 53
    if dense_layer == '0':
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: There's an empty `if` block which is not allowed. Add at least a comment or `pass`.

Comment: `if dense_layer == '0':` _on its own_, without any code _inside the if statement_, is a syntax error. There's not much to be said about it, honestly

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
if dense_layer == '0':
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot the condition after

```
if dense_layer == '0':
```

you have to put something in there, you cannot leave it blank